# <signal.h> header error, could there be something wrong?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
static void p(int sig)
{
puts("It worked!");
exit(1);
}

int main()
{
struct sigaction p;
p.sa_handler = p;
sigemptyset(&p.sa_mask);
p.sa_flags = 0;
if (sigaction(SIGINT, &p, NULL) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error!");
        exit(2);
    }
printf("Please enter your name");
char name[30];
fgets(name, 30, stdin);
printf("Good morning 10%s", name);
return 0;
}
```

Compilation error: Size of 'p' is not known.
What do I do? I've included different header files as well but nothing seems to work and this code is basic, why won't it run?

Comment: You have a function `p` and `struct sigaction` variable named `p`. And they're both visible in the same scope. Proper & distinct naming might help..

Comment: In using signals, you must only use async-signal-safe functions in the signal-handler function (on Ubuntu Linux see list in: man 7 signal) "puts()" is NOT in the async-signal-safe list.

Comment: If you use GCC and `-std=c11` (or `-std=c99`, or — perish the thought — `-std=c90`), then the POSIX extensions are disabled unless you add `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` or equivalent.  Alternatively, use `-std=gnu11` (or another standard year). This problem would account for the 'implicit function definition' warnings — and the 'size of `p` is not known' warning. The diagnosis that you can't use a variable `p` and reference a function `p` after you defined the variable (in [medalib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7383242/medalib)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49702158/15168) is valid.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem here is in the name of the signal handler function, which is the same as the `struct sigaction p`. You have to change its name to something else like:

```
static void sig_handler(int sig)
```

Then change the assignment of `p.sa_handler` too:

```
p.sa_handler = sig_handler;
```

Or you can change the name of the `struct sigaction` to something else.

Comment: warning: Implicit declaration of function 'sigemptyset' (-Wimplicit-function declaration)

Comment: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sigaction' (-Wimplicit-function-declaration)